Python requests.post Returns 401 Status Code
I am trying to open a betslip for a specific event and bet type type (as outlined in section 4.2.1 here https://api.mollybet.com/docs/api/available-requests/betslips-requests).
I was able to login successfully, return the session's metadata (including the token) and create a stream attached to the session. I follow this up by trying to execute a post request with the code specified below:
SlipUrl = "https://api.mollybet.com/v1/betslips/";  SlipJson = {"sport": data[i][1]["sport"], "event_id": data[i][1]["event_id"], "bet_type": bet_types[j]}
header = {"Accept": "application/json", "User-Agent": "api-doc-test-client", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": token};   r = requests.post(SlipUrl, headers= header, json= SlipJson)

I can't seem to identify anything wrong with my request, as it stands. I've tried numerous iterations of it and none seem to work; I receive 401 and 400 status codes.

Did you check if the data you sent is correct ? 401 is unauthorized, 400 is  bad request so data being incorrect

Where did token come from?  Are you sure that value is correct?

@JohnGordon The token was obtained as an output from logging on. In addition, I was also able to confirm it by requesting the metadata associated with the session I'd logged into.

@BDurand so, what you're saying is that, if i repeatedly receive a 401 status for my request, it's not the code which is wrong, but the issue is with the service provider?

Does the API provide documentation for what the headers should be?

Perhaps the API expects a Authorization: Bearer header, instead of just Authorization ?
